# Trying to split a string but I keep getting this error: "Type Error: must be str or None, not list"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Basically, I am trying to generate a random 4 digit number and then split that number and assign each digit to a separate variable. I'm new to python and I honestly have no idea what I am doing, I got the create random number code from the internet as well as the code to split the string so I can't really self diagnose the problem. Any help is appreciated!

```
from random import *
number = randint(1000,9999)
strnumber = str(number)
a,b,c,d = strnumber.split([strnumber[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(strnumber), 1)])
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

The Error message is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\Documents HDD\Python\Mastermind Task.py", line 4, in
>
> a,b,c,d = strnumber.split([strnumber[i:i+1] for i in range(0,
>   len(strnumber), 1)])
>
> TypeError: must be str or None, not list

Edit: Okay, I promise I'm not a complete idiot, I simply copied the wrong thing into the post, I have fixed the rather embarrassing typos.

Comment: You used `strnumber` in some places and `stringnumber` in others in your question. Please paste the exact code you used: this one doesn't correspond to the error message you got.

Comment: A typo: `strnumber` vs `stringnumber`.

Comment: Have you considered reading a basic tutorial until you do understand what you are doing?

Comment: Yep, quite a blunder on my part, but after fixing the typo, i still get the same error message of Type error: must be str or None, not list.

Answer (score 0):

You went too far we can just assign the multiple variables to the `string` directly, but at the same time we can use `map` to make all the variables `int`

```
from random import randint

num = randint(1000,9999)
a, b, c, d = map(lambda x: int(x), str(num))

#  2 4 7 0
# <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

Comment: okay, thanks for that. You where the only one who realised that I'm not an idiot and that I just made typos in the post. Thanks for helping a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

`split()` returns a list of strings, not a string itself. You will have to either parse that out and get the string from it, or since it's a single number, simply cast it with `str()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. You refer to `stringnumber` instead of `strnumber`.
2. You are misusing `str.split`, which takes as an argument a delimiter. This function is not necessary.

So you can use:

```
a, b, c, d = (strnumber[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(strnumber), 1))
```

However, note that strings are themselves *iterable*, so you can unpack directly:

```
a, b, c, d = strnumber
```

Or, if you need integers:

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, strnumber)
```

Alternatively, you can use mathematical operations and obviate the need for conversion between `str` and `int`:

```
from math import log10

d, c, b, a = (number // 10**i % 10 for i in range(int(log10(number))+1))
```

Notice we reverse the assignment order to reflect our calculation.

Answer (score 0):

So right im a noob so i did it a noob's way But works none the less

```
from random import *
number = str(randint(1000,9999))
number = "{}".format(number)

print(number)
TheFour = ['','','','']
pos = 0
for i in number:
    TheFour[pos] = i
    pos += 1
    print(i)

print(TheFour)
a = TheFour[0]
print(a)
b = TheFour[1]
print(b)
c = TheFour[2]
print(c)
d = TheFour[3]
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import *
number = randint(1000,9999)
strnumber = str(number)
a,b,c,d = [int(i) for i in str(strnumber)]
print a
print b
print c
print d
```

Comment: Could you explain in words what was wrong with the original poster's code, and why you chose this solution? That will help people understand why this is a good solution.

Comment: in the original post code ,split() method returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator.  no separator has been specified.